# What does GarbageCollectorMXBean#getCollectionTime mean in G1GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

What does GarbageCollectorMXBean#getCollectionTime mean in G1GC. Is it the sum of pause time(time spent by STW phase) and concurrent phase or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The method getCollectionTime returns a long value of the approximate accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds.

[Java docs on the GarbageCollectorMXBean Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html)

Comment: I'm looking for more detailed answer rather than Javadoc reference. Particularly how does it relate to Pause Time and concurrent phases of GC algorithm. Does that metric include both ?